# How to concatenate 2 LPOLESTR

Tags: c++, string, bho, concatenation, wstring

i want to concatenate 2 strings in c++, i can't use char*.

I tried the following but doesn't work:

```
#define url L"http://domain.com"
wstring s1 = url;
wstring s2 = L"/page.html";
wstring s = s1 + s2;
LPOLESTR o = OLESTR(s);
```

I need a string with s1 and s2 concatenated. Any info or website that explain more about this ? Thanks.

Comment: @Joe: [typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;
](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: There's no `#include <string>` and no `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OLESTR("s")` is the same as `L"s"` (and `OLESTR(s)` is `Ls`), which is obviously not what you want.
Use this:

```
#define url L"http://domain.com"
wstring s1 = url;
wstring s2 = L"/page.html";
wstring s = s1 + s2;
LPCOLESTR o = s.c_str();
```

This gives you a `LPCOLESTR` (ie. a `const LPOLESTR`).  If you *really* need it to be non-const, you can copy it to a new string:

```
...
wstring s = s1 + s2;
LPOLESTR o = new wchar_t[s.length() + 1];
wcscpy(o, s.c_str()); //wide-string equivalent of strcpy is wcscpy
//Don't forget to delete o!
```

Or, to avoid wstring's altogether (**not recommended; it would be better to convert your application to using `wstring`'s everywhere** than to use `LPOLESTR`'s):

```
#define url L"http://domain.com"
LPCOLESTR s1 = url;
LPCOLESTR s2 = L"/page.html";
LPOLESTR s = new wchar_t[wcslen(s1) + wcslen(s2) + 1];
wcscpy(s, s1); //wide-string equivalent of strcpy is wcscpy
wcscat(s, s2); //wide-string equivalent of strcat is wcscat
//Don't forget to delete s!
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the L to make s2's assignment work.

```
wstring s2 = L"/page.html";
```

Comment: just changed it, but it gives me: 'error C2065: 'Ls' : undeclared identifier' on line 'LPOLESTR o = OLESTR(s);'